# Introduction to Computation and Programming using Python, looping

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm studying that book mentioned above. I was solving a problem when I got a simple mistake.

The problem:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer and prints two integers, `root` and `pwr`, such that `0 < pwr < 6` and `root**pwr` is
>   equal to the integer entered by the user. If no such pair of integers
>   exists, it should print a message to that effect.

and that's my code:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter an Integer:'))
root= int(x**0.5)
for pwr in range (1, 6) :
    if x == root**pwr:
        print 'root=', root
        print 'pwr=', pwr
else:
    print"There's no such pair"
```

And the output is:

```
>>> 
Enter an Integer:4
root= 2
pwr= 2
There's no such pair
>>>
```

The mistake is that it still outputs `There's no such pair` even with the right answer. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to `break` the loop when you find a solution, otherwise it ends naturally and the `else` block runs. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Thanks a lot @ jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ jonrsharpe

Here's the answer:

```
x = int(raw_input('Enter an Integer:'))
root= int(x**0.5)
for pwr in range (1, 6) :
    if x == root**pwr:
        print 'root=', root
        print 'pwr=', pwr
        break

else:
    print 'no such pair'
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the problem considers 0 < pwr < 6. Which means that if X is the integer the user enters. the answer is trivial, for any X X=root if pwr = 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a test comment. And this is my first time ever to post a comment here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31294845)